# Why is grep failing to match an equal sign?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep

This works:

```
$ sudo gitlab-runner list 2>&1 | grep 'Token'
Python 2.7.14                                       Executor=docker Token=bccdbf31ef6bc74b2ae4980d8eccea URL=http://something
Docker                                              Executor=docker Token=5b06f034f48d3543848d7d209ce80c URL=http://something
Ansible                                             Executor=docker Token=e2215647f2c9981c8d74abaf324983 URL=http://something
```

This doesn't:

```
$ sudo gitlab-runner list 2>&1 | grep 'Token='
(empty)
```

Why?

I am using:

```
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.25
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others, see <http://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.
```

Comment: @Barmar on SO said to you that the `=` sign can be something different that what you expect, maybe an unicode character. What is the output of `sudo gitlab-runner list 2>&1 | grep -o 'Token..' | od -c` ?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1301664/sed-fails-to-match-equal-sign

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49178981/sed-fails-to-match-equal-sign

Answer (score 1):

Copying and pasting your output from above into grep Token= passes the lines straight through, so there may be some strange unprintable characters in the output from gitlab-runner, between the "Token" and the "=", that have been cleaned up by your paste into superuser.com.