# sed fails to match equal sign

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sed

This is working:

```
$ sudo gitlab-runner list 2>&1 | grep 'Token' | sed -e 's/Token//'
Python 2.7.14                                       Executor=docker =bccdbf31ef6bc74b2ae4980d8eccea URL=http://something
Docker                                              Executor=docker =5b06f034f48d3543848d7d209ce80c URL=http://something
Ansible                                             Executor=docker =e2215647f2c9981c8d74abaf324983 URL=http://something
```

This is not working:

```
$ sudo gitlab-runner list 2>&1 | grep 'Token' | sed -e 's/Token=//'
Python 2.7.14                                       Executor=docker Token=bccdbf31ef6bc74b2ae4980d8eccea URL=http://something
Docker                                              Executor=docker Token=5b06f034f48d3543848d7d209ce80c URL=http://something
Ansible                                             Executor=docker Token=e2215647f2c9981c8d74abaf324983 URL=http://something
```

Whis is this?

I am using:

```
$ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Jay Fenlason, Tom Lord, Ken Pizzini,
and Paolo Bonzini.
GNU sed home page: <http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/>.
General help using GNU software: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>.
E-mail bug reports to: <bug-sed@gnu.org>.
Be sure to include the word ``sed'' somewhere in the ``Subject:'' field.
```

### EDIT

It seems the output has indeed strange chars:

```
$ sudo gitlab-runner list 2>&1 | grep 'Token' | od -c

0000340   o   c   k   e   r       T   o   k   e   n 033   [   0   ;   m
0000360   =   5   5   6   1   a   c   1   c   3   0   9   4   c   3   8
0000400   0   e   1   a   3   0   e   3   5   0   2   5   d   a   5    
0000420   U   R   L 033   [   0   ;   m   =   h   t   t   p   :   /   /
```

Comment: Check if there are any invisible characters in there: `sudo gitlab-runner list 2>&1 | grep 'Token' | od -c`

Comment: Kind of same question/answer https://superuser.com/questions/1301663/why-is-grep-failing-to-match-an-equal-sign

Comment: Different tools, not sure if the problem is the same (but probably ...)

Comment: Same user, same problem

Comment: It's ansi escape sequences. Can you configure `gitlab-runner` to output in raw mode

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46562048/parsing-token-value-from-gitlab-runner-output-containing-ansi-escape-attributes

Comment: `grep -Po 'Token=\K[a-f0-9]{30}'`